# Botframework Web Application Azure IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework

We have a issues with our bot

It was working fine during the last 4 months without any errors.

But today we receive the relevant error :

```
2018-12-17T17:50:25  PID[5736] Error       
Error refreshing OpenId configuration: System.InvalidOperationException: 
    IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. 
            ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. 
            ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
            ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
            ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
            ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The complete log file was shown at this link : https://pastebin.com/ZLx9G9W7

I think it's a exception due too IIS configuration but we have not changed anything on that.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: I'm experiencing issues as well. In my case it is `IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration'` My application ran since January this year and suddenly it stopped working throwing these errors. I'm using botframework v3, which version do you use @pascal?

Comment: Hi Arnold, i'm using the same version V3 our web app was deployed on May/June. 
We have a othe bot (V3) deployed on september and this work fine.

Comment: @ArnoldPistorius I'm trying to up my reference package to the last v3 release (v3.19.1.144133) i'm refresh the post if find a way :)..

Comment: I have tried that, but didn't work for me. I've posted a tweet so Azure support is aware of this issue: https://twitter.com/arniejj/status/1075006618365059072

Comment: Thanks you, it's same for me. The off v3 release (v3.19.1.144133)  doesn't work and have same issues. 
But i didn't say why 1 bot have issues and other was style running. I'm going to try change the APP_SECRET it's can be the solution ...

Comment: I have submitted a support ticket to the azure tech guys. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks you, @ArnoldPistorius I'm going to submit ticket too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I have had a phone call with an engineer from Microsoft. They told me BotFramework doesn't support TLS 1.0 anymore and we have to migrate to version 1.2. They have anounced this in a blog post: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/11/06/announcement-azure-bot-service-enforcing-transport-layer-security-tls-1-2/

My bot was fixed by adding this line in the startup code (in my case it was Application_Start in Global.asax.cs):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. You saved my week. Our bot work gread with the line add. Thanks you.

Comment: @AmolPawar hi have you find way to V4 SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old, but I just ran into this exact error message yesterday with an Azure App Service (Bot Framework v4.15):

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration'.

The issue was that the App Service had lost the ability to resolve DNS. This was confirmed by opening the Kudu Debug Console and running:

`nameresolver.exe login.botframework.com` (and any other hostname)

Unfortunately, this was a temporary outage of some sort on Microsoft's end (currently being investigated with MS support). I had to deploy a separate plan and App Service in order to restore service. Frustratingly, the broken App Service started magically working again the next morning.